# How to detect a gap in series data by individual?

Tags: r

My problem is basically like this:

[How to detect a gap in series data using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516289/how-to-detect-a-gap-in-series-data-using-r)

but additionally my data contains diverse data series of different individuals that are in another column (`id`) . My time-data is in `POSIXct` format.

So far, I did this:

```
# Take rows 1 to n-1 and subtract rows 2 to n:
my_dat$gap <- c(NA, with(my_dat, time[-1] - time[-nrow(my_dat)]))

# now, how often was the gap more than some amount of time?
gap_threshold <- 30 # let's say, 30 seconds (I used another interval)
my_dat$over_thresh <- my_dat$gap > gap_threshold
my_dat

# result: timestamp, difference from prior row in seconds, threshold test 
result
# > my_dat
#                   time       gap over_thresh id
# 1  2015-05-28 16:28:05        NA          NA A
# 2  2015-05-28 16:28:46 40.852095        TRUE A
# 3  2015-05-28 16:29:35 49.060379        TRUE A
# 4  2015-05-28 16:29:55 20.290983       FALSE B
# 5  2015-05-28 16:30:02  6.580322       FALSE C
# 6  2015-05-28 16:30:34 32.039323        TRUE B
# 7  2015-05-28 16:30:58 24.601907       FALSE B
# 8  2015-05-28 16:31:16 17.761954       FALSE A
# 9  2015-05-28 16:31:51 34.794329        TRUE D
# 10 2015-05-28 16:32:35 44.213900        TRUE D
```

So my question is, how I can find gaps for each `id` separately?

Comment: Do a group by for each 'id' i.e. `with(my_dat,ave( time, id, function(x) c(NA, x[-1]-x[-length(x)]) > 30))`

Comment: if you're looking for a base R solution try `l <- split(my_dat,factor(my_dat$id)` and then `lapply(l,somefunction)`. Btw; use `dput(my_dat)` to provide us with a reproducible example, so we can give you back a working example.

Comment: Or use `dplyr` i.e. `my_dat %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(over_thresh = (time -lag(time, default = time[1])) > 30)`